# Angular 2 Hybrid App: Unknown provider: ng2.ComponentFactoryRefMapProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive, components, upgrade

## Scenario

I'm trying to use a very simple angular 2 (rc.5) component as a directive inside my angular 1.5 app but I'm getting an error when adding the directive to one of my modules.

## Error

`[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ng2.ComponentFactoryRefMapProvider <- ng2.ComponentFactoryRefMap <- dummyDirective`

## Code

### Angular2

*jspm command for bundling*: `jspm bundle-sfx embeddedModule.ts dist/component-sfx.min.js --skip-source-maps --format global --global-name __myglobal`

This component-sfx.min.js gets moved over into the proper location within the angular1 project

**embeddedModule.ts**

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'core-js/client/shim.js';
import 'zone.js';
import 'reflect-metadata/Reflect';

import { UpgradeAdapter, UpgradeAdapterRef } from '@angular/upgrade';
import { Component, provide, Inject, NgModule, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';

const adapter = new UpgradeAdapter(forwardRef(() => EmbeddedModule));

@Component({
    selector: 'dummy',
    template: '<p>Hello!</p>'
})
class DummyComponent {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Dummy.constructor...');
    }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  declarations: [
      DummyComponent
  ]
})
class EmbeddedModule {}

var downgradedComponent = adapter.downgradeNg2Component( DummyComponent );

export { adapter, DummyComponent, downgradedComponent };
```

### Angular 1 app

**index.html**

```
<script src=... angular vendor scripts ...></script>
<script src="path/to/my/angular2-sfx.js></script>
```

**main.js**

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  ...
  angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['my-app']);
  ...
});
```

**my.controller.js** (where I actually want to use my downgraded component)

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('data-gov-reference.state.index')
        .controller('MyController', Index)
        .directive('dummy', __myglobal.adapter.downgradeNg2Component(DummyComponent));

    function Index() {
        console.log('MyController...');
    }


}());
```

**myview/myview.html** (the view where I want the downgraded directive to show up)

```
<div>
  <dummy></dummy>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, figured out the issue.

In main.ts, `angular.bootstrap(...)` should have been `__myglobal.adapter.bootstrap(...)`

**main.ts**

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  ...
  __myglobal.adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['my-app']);
  ...
});
```

Hope it helps someone else!

Comment: You can mark you answer as accepted as well :)